# is there a way to destructor the self object like javascript?

Tags: python-3.x

I've started to write python, and I come into the self that you write inside of a class.

```py
  def start_simulator(self):
        while True:
            cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(str(i) + '.ply')
            self.vis.clear_geometries()
            self.vis.add_geometry(cloud)
            self.vis.poll_events()
            self.vis.update_renderer()
            if self.inputQueue.qsize() > 0:
                input_str = self.inputQueue.get()
                if input_str == "stop":
                    self.inputQueue.empty()
                    break
```

now I see myself writing a lot of self.

is there a way to use a destructor to self? Like in javascript:

```js
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman',
  realName: 'Bruce Wayne'
};

const { name, realName } = hero; //something like this
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dataclasses decorator in python its the closest data structure in python i know

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class hero:
   name: str
   realName: str
```

you can check this website:
https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/